# Code Igniter: Data not being posted due to validation

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, model-view-controller

```
 <?php  

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$task = $_POST['name'];
$count = $_POST['choice'];
$order = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `Dreams` (Choice, Name) VALUES   
('$count', '$task')");
$order->execute();
}

 ?>
```

I'm trying to submit information from a form input on a View in code igniter. This code above is at the end, and should submit name and choice.

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                    $this->load->view('bar');
                 echo validation_errors(); 
            }
            else
            {
                   $this->load->view('formsucess');

            }
```

These lines of code are in my controller which begin validation. The problem I'm having is that the first set of code is not executing, and actually pushing the data to the server(the connection and info are all correct, being verified at the beginning of the view's code that establishes the connection). I believe it's because the controller tries to validate before the view can actually push the form data to the database. How do I reconcile this without having to make too many drastic changes?

Comment: Try $this->form_validation->run() === false

Comment: @Just_Do_It that didn't do anything

Comment: One more thing since u are using CI so ideally you should get values as: $task = $this->input->post('name', true); instead of $task = $_POST['name'];

Comment: @cfnerd it's saying no queries were run, which is my original assumption of what was happening. Although I really do appreciate there  the decent diagnostics tool. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help.  Reading closer, is the top portion ( isset() ) running in the view itself?  If so, move that into the controller.

Comment: @cfnerd done so. The data is posting but the query isn't being executed.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was outside of my question. Focused too hard on these aspects to not see that the forms input value was "Submit Form" and not "submit"

```
<input type "submit" name "submit" value "Submit Form"> <--- wrong
<input type "submit" name "submit" value "submit"> <---- correct
```